# what are the standard practice to over come indentation error in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python whenever I am trying to write the nested for loop with some if statement I cam coming across this indentation error. I am interested to know where the block start and block ends and how python identifies it if it does not use the command END that other programming language uses. Below is my sample code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as im



img = im.imread('OD6.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

R=img[:,:,0]
G=img[:,:,1]
B=img[:,:,2]


M,N=R.shape

gray_img= np.zeros((M,N))
intensity= np.zeros((M,N))

for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            gray_img[i, j]=(R[i, j]*0.2989)+(G[i, j]*0.5870)+(B[i, j]*0.114);

t=127


for i in range(1, M-1):
    for j in range(1, N-1):
        intensity[i,j]=gray_img[i,j]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation

Comment: I tried your code either in Jupyter Notebook or Spyder and it works without any error!

Comment: Impossible !. I am getting error in spyder. Did you edited the code?

Comment: In the code there is definitly a problem, as the indents in the two loops are different. The standard indent is 4 spaces

Comment: @acousticpython Check it out [Spyder](https://i.imgur.com/B5quFow.png) and [JN](https://i.imgur.com/Nvo0NLR.png) without any edit!

Comment: I see there is an extra indentation in 2nd for loop use shift + Tab and remove `;` but they don't reflect any indentation error as I showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is not a Spyder, but a Python related question. As pointed out in the comments, you can find the official documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)

Whereas in `Java` you would have something like this:

```
for(int i, i<100, i++) {
[...]
}
```

where everything within the `{..}` is within the loop, in `Python` the indent level shows its association.

```
for i in range(100):
    #Indent by one tab belongs to the loop
    [...] 
#Everything 'unindented' afterwards, is outside of the loop
```

Another Example

```
#Function A is defined
def A():
    #Indented stuff is within the function
    [...]
    for i in range(100):
        #Everything indented twice is within the loop
        [...]
    #Here we are outside the loop, but inside the function

#Here we are outside the function and can call it
x = A()
```

Comment: This question and answer could be easily googled by OP or you could just address OP to the relative link in a comment.

Comment: I do agree, nevertheless, I feel the 5 minutes effort in a short answer are well spent if others do come by the question